What's the idea behind plea deals?
From my perspective (as a citizen of a country on the east side of the Atlantic) the weight put on plea deals in the judicial system of the US seems weird.
If the state has a solid case, there is no need for a plea deal.
If there is no solid case, then there is "innocent until proven otherwise". No plea deal needed.
What do I miss?

You're missing the fact that juries convict people on less-than-solid cases every day.

@bdb484 And they also acquit people who surely did it (e.g. OJ) because the evidence is not as solid as necessary ("beyond a reasonable doubt").

What do you mean by "solid case"?

Worth noting that lots of cases are reasonably low stakes, factually simple, and open and shut cases on liability and don't secure a huge discount in sentencing (although there are cases that do). Probably fewer than 15% of cases that get referred by law enforcement for prosecution involve any meaningful uncertainty over guilt. About 95% of criminal prosecutions result some criminal conviction or deferred judgment sentence (in round numbers 90% plea, 5% convict at trial, 5% acquit at trial, although there is quite a bit of variation in these percentages by jurisdiction).

@Barmar I don't know how you can say someone "surely did it" if the evidence isn't solid beyond a reasonable doubt.

@bdb484 Everyone knows (and most knew then) that he did it. The police botched the investigation, so the evidence that could be presented in court was not good enough.

How is it that "most knew" he did it? I suspect very few had access to information that would allow them to "know" that. Might it be more accurate to say that lots of people assumed he did it, and happened to be correct on this occasion?

@bdb484 OK, we know it now, since he lost the civil case. And have you forgotten the infamous white Bronco chase -- he was trying to escape. It was patently obvious. But that's not admissible evidence.

@bdb484 Botched investigation. Lawyers + media made this to a racist case, making nearly all blacks to believe he is innocent, and nearly all whites to believe he is guilty. It was not long after the Rodney King case, and politics did not want yet another riot with likely more deaths. In theory, judges/jury are not needed to follow politics, but sometimes they do, beside that they might follow the same rationality.

@Barmar Civil cases are decided on the balance of evidence, whereas criminal guilt requires proof beyond reasonable doubt. We can say that OJ probably did it, but the criminal acquittal means we can't say he definitely did it.

@PaulJohnson As a matter of law, that's true. As a matter of common understanding, I believe there's little doubt.

@PaulJohnson Sometimes juries just get it wrong. They aren't perfect.

FYI, The United States has about 50 lawyers for every judge (1,400,000 lawyers and about 28,000 judges including magistrates and federal administrative law judges), while Europe has about 1.5 lawyers for every judge (somewhat more than a million lawyer and about 700,000 judges). The U.S. has a population of 333 million, giving it one judge per 11,893 people, while Europe has a population of 448 million, giving it one judge per 640 people (excluding lay judges). The combined number of lawyers and judges per thousand people is about 233 in the U.S. and 249 in Europe. This is a factor in this.

There is the theory, and there is the practice.
In theory, any defendant has the right to bring all arguments in her or his defense, both to demonstrate that the prosecution did not meet their burden of proof, and if they did (or even if not) that there are mitigating circumstances. A defendant who simply pleads guilty would abandon the latter option. So a plea deal means the defendant gets an assurance what an admission of guilt brings.
In practice, plea deals have become a way of reducing the workload of the prosecution and courts. Defendants "get the book thrown at them" in the expectation that they will bargain it down significantly and come to a fair sentence as a result. Defendants who insist on their right to a jury trial face the risk of a grossly disproportionate sentence because they do not get the common rebate which is implicitly factored into sentencing guidelines.
In theory, any defendant has the right to remain silent if a statement would implicate him or her of a crime. When there are multiple perpetrators in a crime, it is common to reward those who voluntarily provide evidence for crimes which could not be proven without this evidence with a more lenient sentence. But a defendant who can provide such evidence is usually facing significant punishment, and putting it into a plea deal rather than hoping for the lenience of the court gives her or him reassurance which makes it possible to "do the moral thing."
In practice, there is the quip that when one is accused of a drug crime, one had better be guilty, because the innocent cannot betray any accomplices to buy their sentence down.
Plea deals are especially pernicious in combination with cash bail. Defendants who cannot make bail are pressured to plead guilty, even if they are innocent, to get through their trial more quickly.

The average legal fees for the prosecution and the public defender combined in a state court felony prosecution (including both plea bargained and tried cases) is under $100 US. Plea bargaining saves an immense amount of resources.

@ohwilleke, at a lawyer's hourly rate that's hardly enough to open the file, let alone read it end to end. So how much decision power does the practice hand to the police who decide to file a case?

Prosecutors and public defenders are both at the low end of the pay scale, but the amount of time spent by the lawyers per case that pleas is typically less than twenty to thirty minutes per case. Pleas are entered orally so there is no need to write up a written document. Law enforcement provides a police report to the prosecutor and maybe a quick chat with the prosecutor. Police gather evidence but have little say over what is charged or what plea is entered. Capital cases that go to trial or plea at the last minute often take up close to half of their budget.

There are many cases where people facing less serious charges are nevertheless held on remand for so long that the plea deal is "time served". This puts an innocent person in a terrible position: plead guilty and walk free today (with a criminal record), or insist on a trial and stay in jail for an indeterminate time.

@PaulJohnson Indeed, which is why there has been a long running attempt to secure bail reform which has been successful in a few places, and not successful in many others.

You miss that even if the state has a solid case, it saves everyone's time to avoid the trial. Trial demands resources and attention from many people. Keeping the easily proved cases out of court frees up resources for other matters. It can also be a benefit to potential witnesses or victims and their families, who may be retraumatized by participating in a trial.
For the accused / offender, the benefit may be lenience about the sentence. Pleading guilty is seen as a mitigating factor on sentencing. It is seen as accepting responsibility. The prosecutor may even agree to only proceed with a subset of charges in exchange for the plea.
You are correct there is no "need" for a plea deal. It is never necessary in any given case. But it is often attractive to both sides and is necessary as a practice from an institutional perspective.

While it is never necessary in any given case, as least in the U.S., it is necessary institutionally. The amount of resources that would be necessary to try every case where a defendant wasn't willing to plea guilty without some concession would be maybe 4x to 10x what they today. The system would collapse in the short run. There have been some isolated instances where the defense bar has collectively stopped making pleas to address grievances, although there are ethical issues with that and they have been few and short.

But if might be beneficial for an innocent person to take a plea deal over a trial shows to me that the system is severly broken...

@kreumi Sometimes a plea deal result is better than a trial result would be likely to be. The evidence available could make an innocent person look guilty and likely to be convicted. Or, e.g., the statutory penalty that is usually fair may be excessive in the facts of the case and the plea deal provides a safety valve to address that. Empirically, innocent people are much less likely to plea guilty than guilty ones, and the sentencing trial penalty for those people if the jury gets it wrong is the biggest injustice in those cases.

Jury trials are always a gamble
There is no such thing as a “sure thing” in US courts. There are plenty of examples of juries finding verdicts some people would consider shocking (for example, OJ Simpson).
Plea deals offer the chance for a compromise rather than requiring either side to take the gamble. Often, plea deals tend to be influenced by the “odds” - like the state will offer a relatively poor deal if their evidence is extremely strong, but they are likely to offer a better deal if they are less certain about getting a conviction.

The best empirical estimates of errors in jury verdicts is that there is an irreducible 10% error rate, even in cases where the lawyers and judges do everything right.

A bench trial is usually an option for the defendant.

@user71659 Jury trial are almost always chosen in state courts, because in state courts they acquit at about twice the rate of judges, on average.

'There is no such ting as a "sure thing"'... Ok. So this would mean that plea deals are basically a try to get around a fundamentally broken system? If it can be benefical for someone who is not guilty to plea guilty. Or if someone who is not guilty has to face a higher risk of prosecution than someone quilty of takes a plea deal?

@kruemi The system doesn't have to be fundamentally broken, just imperfect. The inherent uncertainty in a jury reaching the right verdict in a criminal trial (empirically) is roughly 10%. Even if no one's rights are violated and the lawyers and judges do their jobs properly, the jury reaches the wrong result one time in ten. In a particular case, the odds of an incorrect verdict may be much greater because the available admissible evidence makes the defendant look guilty, e.g., because their alibi witness is dead, or a key witness is likely to lie at trial in a way that can't be disproven.

The prosecution may have a solid case but it will involve man-hours to bring it to court. The defendant may have a credible defense but that involves paying a lawyer for the duration of the trial. If the two sides can reach an agreement that mitigates both the cost to the state and the cost to the defendant, that may be a win to both.

Some of the answers miss the underlying motivation.  Municipal attorney generals are elected positions and poorly paid for the skill involved.  Essentially they are running a law firm of prosecutors but are paid more like a new associate.  However, most have political aspirations.  A state governorship is frequently the goal and within reach.  Once a person becomes a governor, the presidency is not out of the question.
How does an attorney general (AG) get to the next higher officer, or at least stay the attorney general?  By having a lot of convictions with a low budget.  "Getting criminals off the street, quickly". A common way to do this is with plea deals.
Person A is caught robbing person B.  With a trial, person A might be convicted in about a year or two.  If he makes bail, he may rob and be caught again.  This is very bad for the AG.  One such incident, with poor timing, could result in the AG being thrown out of office.
Instead the AG makes a deal to with A to do 6 months and pay restitution to B.  The deal is done in a few weeks.  This is seen as positive, and can be touted in the AGs campaign.
"Not only did we get hardened criminals off the streets, but we made them pay restitution to their victims".

Is it only my feeling or is there really a tendency that a conviction (any conviction) is more important than to find the real criminal?

@kruemi  I think books can be written about just the psychology of such and answering is well beyond my capability.  However, for some, there seems to a benefit for finding a perpetrator and having them punished.  It seems to bring closure.

@kruemi Keep in mind that 95%+ of people who are arrested and charged with a crime are guilty of some crime. Most of the criminal justice system and most of a defense lawyer's job is geared to getting an appropriate charge and an appropriate sentence for the actual crime committed. People who are innocent of any crime who are convicted does happen and is bad, but this is far from being the most serious problem with the U.S. criminal justice system, and that percentage can never be reduced entirely to zero. Probably 90%+ of prosecutors will never try to convict someone doubting their guilt.

@ohwilleke "prosecutors will never try to convict someone doubting their guilt".  This is most certainly false.

@PeteB It isn't true for 100% of prosecutors, but it is true for about 90% of them (and is a reasonable paraphrase of the relevant ethical rule). The "bad" 10% are also disproportionately in states where there is a history of racism and disregard for defendant's rights in the criminal justice system (like most of the former Confederate States).

That the minority of the white hats in the legal systems recognize: they lost, and surrender with conditions.
